# Fullcalendar - Shows double events when embedded in another page

Tags: calendar, fullcalendar

I have embedded the full calendar in a JQuery Accordion panel. But is shows double events. If I do not embed it in the Accordion panel then it works fine.

Any ideas? Has anyone faced this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: please create js fiddle and explain a bit more, there are some issues with accordian an popups but there is a solution, just give me a visual